# select an option from dynamically added JS capybara with time based ID

Tags: rspec, capybara

I'm using a Railscasts based js code for adding a new Lesson to my page.

When testing with Rspec and Capybara, how do I select an Option from a dynamically generated select menu, with a unique ID based on time?

My thought, is to final all select menus, and grab the last one, but nothing is clicking with me.

Rspec code:

```
        click_link "Edit "
        click_link "Add Another Lesson" #this then uses JS to put another select menu on the screen.
        select("Lesson 2", from: "#{ideally it would find the last select tag here}") #this is what i don't know how to find.
```

I know there is `all`  but not sure how to use Xpath to find the last select tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dude got me far, thanks @Andrey.

What worked for me was, for text_field inputs:

`all(:css, '.hearter')[0].set "Just Awesome Man"`

for select tags:

`all(:css, '.js-select')[0].select("1") # "1" was my value`

Comment: ```select 'Just Awesome Man', from: '.hearter'``` is what worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

[Actions#select](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Actions#select-instance_method) can find element only by name, id or label text. You don't have it so you should use [Element#select_option](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Element#select_option-instance_method). I don't know of any CSS or XPath selector that will select last element on entire page so I think you can use:

`all('select').last.find(:option, 'Lesson 2').select_option`

Finding all selects but using only the last one may look a bit ugly. It may be better to select it within another element:

```
find(some_selector).find('select').find(:option, 'Lesson 2').select_option
```

Comment: If i remember it wasn't actually picking the option in the generated selector. I'll be able to get into it later this week. thanks.